# If $x = a + b$, and only $x$ is known, how to solve what is $a-b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $x$ equals to $a+b$, how can I solve what is $a-b$, knowing only $x$? (approximation will do as well, if it cannot be solved exactly)

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve for $a-b$, but you can restrict the solutions to a line.

If $x = a+b$, then $b = x-a$, so $a-b = a-(x-a) = 2a-x.$

Therefore, all possible solutions will lie along the line $c = 2a-x$, where $x$ is your fixed known quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = x + k$, $b = x - k$, where $k$ is anything; then $a-b = 2k$.  In other words, you can't say anything about $a-b$, knowing only the value of $a+b$.